# Need Javascript help for Website

Tags: javascript, html

I have made this webpage, you can check it out here http://www.bettingtowin.net/webcam.html

I have inserted buttons but they are useless at the moment and need your help.

What I need is for the small robot picture to change to another picture according to the button that was pressed.

So when I click "Right Arm" button for e.g. I want the picture associated with that button to load instead of smallrobot.jpg

So basically a really basic javascript code. By the way I am no longer a student so its ok to show me the code ;)

Comment: Your not being a student doesn't prevent you from meeting the requirements for posting here, i.e. showing us what you tried, and explaining exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: If I was being cynical I'd suggest that you'd posted that link to drive traffic to your site too.

Comment: No this isn't homework, it was the final year project I did and had to explain in my report that I never had time to finish it, just wanted to finish it off, for my self.

Comment: awoodland I think you have too much time to spare, you should realize that there is nothing on the page to bring me profit, this is purely for my own pleasure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidenote: You have 2 body-Tags in your source.

First give the image a proper id so you can access it via javascript. Then access it via jQuery a la

```
$('#myImage').attr('src', 'path/To/filename.jpg');
```